# How to fix XML file error?

Tags: xml, google-gadget

I want to add Google gadget for my website so I tried to create an XML file for that gadget. After creating that I uploaded it to my website. While loading the page I found some errors in the file. I tried many times but I didn't. So please fix the error. The XML file is

`<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="How to buy a Javelin" height="350" author="http://www.tracknfieldgear.com" author_email="news.tracknfieldgear@gmail.com" title_url=" http://www.tracknfieldgear.com" screenshot="http://www.tracknfieldgear.com/images-new/how-to-throw-javelin.png" thumbnail="http://www.tracknfieldgear.com/images-new/how-to-throw-javelin.png" description="Tracknfieldgear.com is an online store that contains all kind of athletic equipments including shot put, javelin etc. This gadget is related to javelin"/>
  <Content type="html">

  <![CDATA[

                <iframe  name="How to buy a Javelin?" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="250" height="250" src="http://goanimate.com/user/0xVwaBHeiRFI"></iframe>
  ]]> 
  </Content>

</Module>`

The URL I tried to load is `http://www.tracknfieldgear.com/how-to-buy-javelin-gadget.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it can't find the end of your start tag "ModulePrefs"

Here is the [error message](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/xml-check.cgi?url=http://www.tracknfieldgear.com/how-to-buy-javelin-gadget.xml) from an XML-Validator.

You need a whitespace before the author_email attribute.

```
author="http://www.tracknfieldgear.com" author_email="news.tracknfieldgear@gmail.com"
```